# How to get rid of viscous drops from a circuit board

Tags: board

My mothers Dell Inspiron n7110 was spilt over with red wine and doesn't star anymore. Even the front LEDs don't show up in any case.

I was able to dissemble it using the following guide also gives you an overview of the inner
http://www.insidemylaptop.com/disassemble-dell-inspiron-17r-n7110/

There are viscous drops spread all over the motherboard therefore **my question is how to remove those drops in the most secure (and efficiency) way without causing further damage.**

Since the Notebook was turned off when this happened, but immediately turned on after this to look if everything is still working, I'm not sure if cleaning the motherboard will even help but I want to give it a try.

I would also be very thoughtful  further tips.

(Luckily the hard drive still works)

Comment: *My mothers Dell Inspiron* ... is not a topic of electronic design! Doh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Water method.  Wash with a liberal amount or deionized or distilled water.  Bake at 40°C for 8 hours.  
Check that the oven doesn't overshoot the temperature.  
If there's a battery on the board, be careful, because you may destroy it.  See if you can find the spec for the battery and check how much temperature the it can take.

IPA method.  Wash with 100% isopropyl alcohol (IPA).  Baking is optional, or lower temperature and less time.

If you've turned on a wet circuit board, you may have already destroyed something on it.

P.S.  Your question would work better at SuperUser.